# Why does this javascript based printing cause Safari to refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, safari, webkit

The page I am working on has a javascript function executed to print parts of the page.
For some reason, printing in Safari, causes the window to somehow update. I say somehow, because it does not really refresh as in reload the page, but rather it starts the "rendering" of the page from start, i.e. scroll to top, flash animations start from 0, and so forth.

The effect is reproduced by this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fYmnB/

Clicking the print button and finishing or cancelling a print in Safari causes the screen to "go white" for a sec, which in my real website manifests itself as something "like" a reload. While running print button with, let's say, Firefox, just opens and closes the print dialogue without affecting the fiddle page in any way.

Is there something with my way of calling the browsers print method that causes this, or how can it be explained - and preferably, avoided?

P.S.: On my real site the same occurs with Chrome. In the example fiddle Chrome seems to not show the same behaviour as Safari, though.

Edit: I also tried to have the printing button on a different tag than an `a` anchor, like `span` or `button`, but that didn't help with the problem.

Edit: I run into this problem with Safari 5.1.2 on Mac OS 10.6.8. In the jsfiddle example, the behavior shows as a white "flicker" that covers the whole browser after having clicked the print button and closing (either printing or aborting) the print dialogue.

Edit: Just started a bounty for this question, as I am still looking for an explanation for this browser behaviour. I am more than willing to give more details on the issue. From my experience on SO it is not adviseable to post links to online pages, however I feel the problem is really hard to reproduce. I think the "flicker & re-render" I experience with the posted jsfiddle is hopefully is result of the same problem.

Edit: As explained in the comments, opening a new window containing the current state of the application, then printing and closing that window, might be a fix, but I don't consider it a sufficient answer to the problem at hand.

Comment: Please try `<a href="javascript:void(0)">print</a>​`. I'd guess WebKit adds an empty href to your anchor which would explain that behaviour.

Comment: Hey danwit, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the white "reload" flicker in the jsfiddle remains, as does the "refresh" effect in my actual project.

Comment: I update the question with more system specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem but i recently found a very good Jquery plugin to print only certain part of your webpage.

You should give it a try :) It has a some very cool parameters to customize it to your needs.

Take a look [here](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/).

Why does your page refresh? Here's my answer on that. the window.print() function will print the entire content of your page. So since i read that you only want to print a part of the page, I guess you are using some function to remove all unwanted content from the page for a very short moment, then you call the window.print() function and after that you put all orignal content again on the screen. This results in a very short flash that will look like your page is refreshing and will load all flash parts again.

I had the same problem yesterday and this jquery plugin really helped me out. I hope it will help you too.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Up to date I believe this to be the best answer, and explanation, too. My instincts would be to doubt that hiding and reshowing elements would restart the flash, but I believe that my usage of a seperate print stylesheet or the way I have certain elements print and others not might cause the problem in the way you describe it. While I haven't tested the plugin on the actual project website, my tests so far seem promissing enough! The implementation might need a few tweaks, but I'd say this is the most acceptable workaround. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad i could help you out here :)

Comment: Just adding still: Implemented the printElement plugin in the actual application - works like a charm, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't figure a way to fix the problem you might get a quick fix this way:
`var win=window.open()` the same page you are on
then `win.print()` it, then `win.close()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, thanks for the suggestion. Up until now, the decision was not to make a system like that for a 10% share of Safari-visits on the actual project website, but we've discussed a solution like this. The problem here is that the site is a bit of a ajax/flash mixture, where opening a window with the exact same state would cause a little bit of extra work, so this is something I'd like to avoid. :(

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, I don't have a solution. but since I was able to reproduce this in Safari and Webkit with the fiddle, I thought I'll at least offer my observations:

1. The white-out doesn't happen if you hit Print dialog button right away. You need to wait few seconds before you hit Print to be able to see the white. On OSX 10.6.8 I see the threshold marked by appearance of the spinning beachball.
2. When the mouse stays stationary since the Print button hit, the **page stays white** until you move the mouse again (beachball still spinning).

Hope this will help somehow.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it confirms what I observed, especially 2). Good that you also notice it on the fiddle - that reduces my suspicions towards other parts of my real application as source of error, if other users do indeed also experience in the fiddle.

Comment: Awarded your answer with the bounty. While none of the answers so far solve the problem, your's probably is most helpful in finding out what is wrong here.

Comment: Today in the my software update notification I noticed an update to Safari 5.1.2, which in the details states: "...including fixes (that) Address issues that could cause webpages to flash white". Perhaps it refers to the same issue...

Comment: Thanks for keeping up interest in the issue. Just checked with Safari 5.1.2 myself and the issue still persists, unfortunately.

Comment: Just for the record. Today I updated my Safari to 5.1.2 and the issue is no longer observed for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems `window.print()` is [not part of any standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print), browsers are free to implement it in any way they choose.

The only work-around I can see, if you really have to leave the page as-is,  would be to open another window and print that. Which is a whole other, possibly worse, can of worms.

Comment: Interesting fact to know, however I stillfind the bevaviour in that way odd, that normal window.print calls in safari don't seem to cause this, but for some reason, implementing it in the way I did, does.

Comment: @kontur what do you mean by "normal" calls - what's different about the call in your fiddle, and a successful 'normal' call?

Comment: Well, what I meant is that browsing with Safari I never experienced similar problems on other sites that also call the print dialog via javascript. Thus I assume that it is not Safari's implemented default behaviour that causes this result (neither does my Windows installation of Safari act up like described in the topic).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your function:

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.print()</script>");
```

I am referencing this stack:

[After window.open, can't print in Safari for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167768/after-window-open-cant-print-in-safari-for-mac)

**Update, Try:**

```
document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript'>window.print()</script>");
```

Comment: Can't check this until monday, but I'll try it right away and let your know the outcome.

Comment: Okay, trying this approach the browser window goes completely blank on calling my print function, and the printed document is blank also.

Comment: Try this :  document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript'>window.print()</script>");

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to reproduce this error on Safari for PC, only browser I can currently test on.

Comment: I guess it's because your answer is has nothing to do with preventing the flashing of the page after canceling the print dialog. And it's also hardly the right way call the `print` function because calling `document.write` on a loaded document will always clear contents the contents of the window.

Comment: I'm well aware its not the right way to call the print function.  It was a work around for safari that worked in a prior Stack Overflow issue, so I was just simply trying to solve his error.  Please do not downvote unless you explain why in the future.  Trying alternates to the default behaviour in Safari of the window.print()

Comment: Thanks for the update. Tried that as well, but with the same result, it blanks the page for some reason. +1 from me for trying and suggesting something - weird solutions are sometimes what's needed when looking for a weird bug ,)

Comment: No problem.  Sorry I couldn't help.  You could always say "Oh well"!  Safari only has 5% of the desktop browser share per reference of http://netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0&qpcustomd=0.  and a few other sites.  You may not even want to bother with it.

Comment: Problem is, while the fiddle seems reluctant to reproduce the effect when viewed in Chrome, my live project does indeed show the same effect with Chrome, which raises the relevance quite a bit.

Comment: I'm using Safari 5.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2, Im unable to reproduce the error, I click on the print and the printer dialog appear instantly

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found the following to be an easy, simple solution.

Make your own print function that utilizes `event.preventDefault();`.

I made a standard print button on my page similar to this, and used `onclick` to bind it to a custom print function:

```
<button onclick="printOut()">Print</button>
```

The function for `printOut();` is simple and should look like this:

```
function printOut() {
   event.preventDefault();
   print();
}
```

With this, when a user prints the page, the page does not refresh after. It simply seems to call the print function and go back to the webpage as it was. One thing to note, from your original post, I'm using `@media` queries to print certain parts of a page, not JavaScript. But I did want to create a JavaScript button to print so the user is encouraged to print the page.

I tested this in Safari (16.5.1) and Chrome (114.0.5735.198).

This article was a good refresher on using `event.preventDefault();`:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-default-behavior-in-browser/.

I hope this helps! I know this is 11 years late.