# Safari 17.0 loses session data on window.open and window.print

Tags: javascript, php, html, safari

fI run a site where people can print documents (php/html/javascript).

After the newest Safari update (Mac Sonoma, Safari V17.0), the print window loses session cookies after Safari opens a new tab for it.

**How to repeat:**

1. Create a html document ./index.php where there's a button with `onclick="window.open('./anyfolder/printpage.php', '_blank');`
   Set a session cookie here.
2. Add a print button with `onclick="window.print();"` into the printpage.php.
3. Click the button on index.php. Printpage.php opens in a new tab. Cookies still exist.
4. Click on the print button on the printpage.php. Safari print window opens. Wait a few seconds. Now Cookies are lost.

Doesn't happen on any other browser. It also doesn't happen before the *Safari print window has opened*.

IF you drag the opened printpage.php tab into a new WINDOW before clicking window.print, the session cookies aren't lost. Also, if you create a form that opens the printpage.php into a new tab, sessions aren't lost.

Is there any fix to this?

I have cookie params  samesite set as "lax".

**UPDATE**: So, it seems the example doesn't cause the same behavior. I just can't find the problem. Nothing has changed on my end, only on safari.

Basically:

1. I log in.
2. I open a print window in a new tab. Everything works fine.
3. I open the print dialog. I'm logged out on the background. Even the print window turns full white.

I just don't know what has changed on Safari 17 that could cause this. And I noticed a NEW weirdness: sometimes, buttons that open a new page with window.open just stop working. I had to close the Safari to get them working again.

**UPDATE 2**: So, it seems **opening the print dialog actually changes the page on the previous tab that opened the print page page into an empty page!** It doesn't actually seem to have anything to do with sessions per se. Why safari print dialog does -anything- on the previous page that opened the print page is still beyond me. The page is completely empty with nothing on the address line. Clicking "back" returns to the previous page with sessions intact (if there IS a third page)!

**UPDATE 3:** So it actually seems that an **OLD** bug of safari has returned in a slightly different manner, discussed here: [Why does this javascript based printing cause Safari to refresh the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261335/why-does-this-javascript-based-printing-cause-safari-to-refresh-the-page)

I have to check if the suggested fixes help or not.

**UPDATE 4:** Suggested fixes do not help. However, I noticed that if I close the first tab before clicking print on the second, everything works fine. For some reason, the first window goes blank (and logs out) after a few seconds when the print dialog opens in the second tab.

**UPDATE 5:** Another update. No fix on the latest update on Safari. Tested again, and found out that user isn't logged out if I open the print-dialog with CMD+P or from the Safari "Print..." menu. Then it behaves normally. Using javascript "window.print()" and it kills the session.

**This is clearly a bug in Safari V17.**

Comment: `sessions are lost`....it's not clear what you mean by "sessions are lost". What exact behaviour are you observing?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. What I mean is that all session cookies are gone. After the Safari Print-window opens, they disappear in the background. Only happens on Safari 17.0. And only if the page with the print function is opened with window.open. It doesn't happen if you open the page with a form.

Answer (score 1):

We just hit this issue as well. I believe it is related to blocking the event loop in the opened window. window.print() blocks the event loop while it's printing. It looks like Safari sees this block and kills the process both in the opened window and the opening window. We found the developer console is frozen/unresponsive after.

The fix we found was to wrap the print callback in a timeout so it runs outside the event loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printPage() {
    // Print outside the event loop so Safari doesn't think
    // the page has stalled or crashed.
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.print();
    }, 0);
  }
</script>
<button onclick="printPage()">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the behavior but couldn't. - Version 17.0 (19616.1.27.211.1) - Apple M1

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<button onclick="window.open('./printpage.php', '_blank');">Print preview</button>
```

**printpage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
```

Then opened index.php (through webserver) in my browser -> clicked first button -> clicked second button. The session cookie remains intact.

Please try again with my exact code samples, just to verify it's no bug in Safari that needs to be reported.

**UPDATE**

> [...]Safari basically redirects the pages into an empty page when the print dialog window opens. It can be stopped if you quickly cancel the print dialog. IF the dialog stays open for around 3 seconds, the pages turn blank.

I tried again and sure enough: This time the page to be printed disappeared and turned into "Untitled Page".

I then quit and re-opened Safari and again wasn't able to reproduce that behavior.

Comment: I cannot add images since my account is new, but on my M2 mini pro Safari 17.0 it's still repeatable. Funnily, today, moving the print window tab into a new window no longer helped. It kills the cookies even if the window is out of the original window now.

Comment: Did you try with my code snippets or yours?

Comment: Hey, and thanks for your reply. Read my update on the situation. Safari basically redirects the pages into an empty page when the print dialog window opens. It can be stopped if you quickly cancel the print dialog. IF the dialog stays open for around 3 seconds, the pages turn blank.

Comment: Weird! See my "UPDATE"...

Comment: Yes, it's very strange. It appears to be completely random. I restarted Safari, and true enough, it worked fine once. I tried again, and "poof! " the same behavior returned. Same seems to happen with buttons that use window.open. Sometimes they stop working, and then they work again.

Comment: So, I found out that clicking CMD+P keeps the sessions intact. Only clicking the window.print -button causes safari print-dialog to kill the sessions. This is weird.

Comment: Indeed. Did you file a bug report with Apple?

Comment: I have not yet.